# Weighted Issue Prioritization in Jira

Tags: jira, product, jira-agile

I'm a product manager, so I want to be able to collect data on my issues in Jira and automatically see a calculated priority value of this issue:

- I have a set of standardized metrics that I can apply to my tickets:
  Urgency, Count of users impacted, Strategic Focus, Issue Value, LOE
  and the like.
- Each of these metrics has some numerical value that can
  be added up to get a score. This numerical value is a representation
  of a picklist. E.g. Hotfix = 5, Critical = 3, Trivial = 1. Each of
  these metrics has some weight when compared to each other, e.g.
  Urgency counts 15% towards a final score, LOE counts 20%.
- I use these
  values to calculate a priority score like this: (Metric1 *
  WeightMetric1) + (Metric2 * WeightMetric2) + (Metric3 *
  WeightMetric3) + (Metric4 * WeightMetric4) + (Metric5 *
  WeightMetric5) = SCORE
- Metrics and WeightMetric are global values
  that I want to be able to change at times to accommodate shifting
  priorities and focuses.

I would like to be able to:

STORE global values for Metric and WeigthMetric

CALCULATE a score based on the global values selected for each issue

CHANGE global values as needed

Anyone ever tried that? Anyone a clue if Jira can pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you'll get from JIRA out of the box, but you can script that behaviour if you're willing to use a commercial add-on like [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview).

Script Runner supports "script fields". Which are field that calculate their value based on whatever script you put together. Once you have that, you'll be able to use your field in search filter, gadgets, reports, etc.

More info is available in the [documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/5.0.15/jira/scripted-fields.html).